# How can I add a sudo user to WSL using commands in powershell?

Tags: powershell, passwords, sudo, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to automate the WSL setup using powershell scripts.
I have Ubuntu 18.04 distro installed for WSL in my windows 10 system.

I want to run the following commands in powershell to setup a sudo user `tec` with password `1` in WSL.

```
Ubuntu1804 run useradd -m tec
Ubuntu1804 run usermod --password $(echo 1 | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) tec
Ubuntu1804 run usermod -aG sudo tec
```

The problems is, password is not set correctly with the second command. Trying to become the root user ends up in

```
 sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

If I enter to WSL by typing `bash` from windows command prompt, and then execute the following command :

```
usermod --password $(echo 1 | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) tec
```

It sets the password correctly. After that I can become root user by entering the password `1` when prompted.

Can anyone help me to find where I am going wrong with the powershell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer. 
Just wrapping the encrypted password in the second command with single quote worked perfectly.

```
Ubuntu1804 run usermod --password '$(echo 1 | openssl passwd -1 -stdin)' tec
```

Now the powershell commands to create a sudo user `tec` with password `1` for WSL looks like :

```
# Creates the user
Ubuntu1804 run useradd -m tec

# sets password for user
Ubuntu1804 run usermod --password '$(echo 1 | openssl passwd -1 -stdin)' tec

# adds user to the sudo group
Ubuntu1804 run usermod -aG sudo tec
```